# Do I need special security for a Restful Account Key from Google Sheets?

Tags: rest, api, google-sheets, oauth-2.0

In the shipedge example, do I need any special security when using account/key combination to grab this information and pull into Google Sheets? - how do I keep that key secret when making a call? - https://www.shipedge.com/help/inventory-api-rest-2/ - I'm familiar with OAuth2 and other security protocols but if that key is in a normal GET, is it a security risk?

Comment: What do you mean with account/key? You maybe could read some material in OAuth authentication. Maybe try [this page from the documentation](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2) and after that try to clarify your problem. Responding to your question, your secret key is protected because the HTTP request is done through a SSL connection (or in other words HTTPS) encrypting your token.

Comment: I mean the account/key at the link I posted. but are you saying as long as I do a get through https, that's sufficient security?

Comment: I think I have misunderstood your setup. You want to make API request to the Google API to insert in sheets? Or do you want to retrieve data FROM sheets, thus making http request from sheets itself? 
If the former you could try to use `Apps Script` and use the [`UrlFetchApp`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app).

Comment: Right. I have UrlFetchApp using the account/key combination they provided. It's a simple GET with that key. no OAuth

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with the REST API you posted but yes, the layer of protection you have for the API key is HTTPS.

That encryption (SSL) should be enough to protect your key and in case your key is lost/compromised the API should have the option to revoke that key and create a new one.

If you were not using the HTTPS protocol you would be very unprotected against [Man-in-the-middle attack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Man-in-the-middle_attack).

You could think that OAuth2 authentication method also relies on the HTTPS protocol for its encryption.